# Plotting multiple graphs from a list in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

I am writing a code to track the performance of financial assets.

This is what I've done so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
library(magrittr)

start_date <- as.Date("2020-01-02")
end_date <- as.Date("2023-04-12")

ETF_list <- list("WTEE.DE", "VGWD.DE")

for (i in ETF_list){
  getSymbols(i, 
              from = start_date, to = end_date,
              src = "yahoo")}

# Plot the data

chartSeries(VGWD.DE,
            theme = chartTheme("white"), # Theme
            name = str(VGWD.DE), # Name
            bar.type = "hlc", # High low close 
            up.col = "green", # Up candle color
            dn.col = "red",  # Down candle color
            TA = list("addVo()", #Volume
                      "addEMA(n = 200, on = 1, col = 'blue')", 
                      "addEMA(n = 50, on =1, col = 'red')"))
```

This works fine for a single element of the list. But when I try to plot all the elements at once with this modified version of the code:

```
for (i in ETF_list){
  chartSeries(i,
              theme = chartTheme("white"), # Theme
              name = str(i), # Name
              bar.type = "hlc", # High low close 
              up.col = "green", # Up candle color
              dn.col = "red",  # Down candle color
              TA = list("addVo()", #Volume
                        "addEMA(n = 200, on = 1, col = 'blue')", 
                        "addEMA(n = 50, on =1, col = 'red')"))}
```

I get this:
Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") :
chartSeries requires an xtsible object

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your current code, it seems that you do not save the output of the loop that includes `getSymbols()`.

If you are new to R, remember that for loops don't produce objects alone. you have to create a placeholder object before the loop and use the loop to populate it.

Example:

```
a= 1:10
for(i in a){ i^2}
print(max(a)) # ==10, the loop did not change anything.

a= 1:10
b= numeric() # placeholder object)
for(i in a){ b=c(b,i^2)} #adding i^2 to the bottom of b
print(max(b)) # ==100, the loop changed the result.
```

Your code is behaving as the first case, so when you call `chartSeries`, you are calling it in the object `list("WTEE.DE", "VGWD.DE")` which is not a time series.